# Inserting string into jsonb type postgres

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a function that generates a prepared statement for batch insert into postgres where I am trying to insert the string into type jsonb in postgres.

My struct looks like:

```
type struct1 struct {
id int
comment string
extra string
}
```

and my table schema looks like:

```
create table deal (
id bigserial,
comment varchar(75),
extra jsonb
)
```

and I want to dump []struct1 to Postgres DB "deal".

My function which generates the prepared statement looks like this:

```
func BulkInsert(str []struct1, ctx context.Context) string {
    log.Debug("inserting records to DB")
    query := fmt.Sprintf(`insert into deal (%s) values `, strings.Join(dbFields, ","))
    var numFields = len(dbFields)
    var values []interface{}
    for i, database := range str {
        values = append(values, database.Comment,`'`+database.Extra+`'`)
        n := i * numFields
        query += `(`
        for j := 0; j < numFields; j++ {
            query += `$` + strconv.Itoa(n+j+1) + `,`
        }
        query = query[:len(query)-1] + `),`
    }
    query = query[:len(query)-1]
        return query
```

Expected results should be: I should be able to insert string to json or you can say cast string to json and dump it.

The actual result is : 
`could not save batch: pq: invalid input syntax for type json"`

Comment: Have you tried `\`'\`+database.Extra+\`'::jsonb\``? And does `database.Extra` hold valid json format?

Comment: Yes but database.Extra can be optional so I might get it sometimes and might not. And ````'`+database.Extra+`'::jsonb```` do not work I tried

Comment: An empty `''` (single quote string) is *invalid* json. So if extra is empty you have to provide "some" json, e.g. `'{}'`, or `'""'`.

Comment: The other problem is, I think, that you're wrapping that string in the single quotes. That's the db driver's job. Try this for non-empty Extra values `values = append(values, database.Comment, database.Extra)` and this for empty values `values = append(values, database.Comment, \`""\`)`.

Comment: Also, my first comment is wrong. When needed, the `::jsonb` should be appended to the parameter reference (`$2::jsonb`) and not the parameter itself.

Comment: Try something like this https://play.golang.com/p/w8aLXzT2hvH

Comment: @mkopriva it worked. I liked the way you played with strings. Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

Function of `json_build_array('exp1'::Text, 'exp2'::Text)` may help you.

> return json object: {'exp1', 'exp2'}

And extract the values just use operator `->><index>` like `->>1` to get 'exp2'.

If you just want to insert into database, function of `to_json('any element')` should also works, which can convert any element to a json object.

And you can get more funtions about json(jsonb) in [postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html).